# Javascript is not working on page change in Astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have the following code in my Header.astro component:

```
const burger = document.querySelector("#burger");
const nav = document.querySelector("#nav");

if (burger && nav) {
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => nav.classList.toggle("on"));
}

var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("hc");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".c").classList.toggle("on");
    this.classList.toggle("hc-down");
  });
}
```

This only works on page load. I understand it is because the DOM is not being reloaded (?). But unfortunately I can't find the solution. I have tried adding is: inline to my script tags but the problem persists.

I have tried adding is: inline to my script tags. I have read about using data-role="page" on other frameworks.

Comment: Are you using Astro's view transitions feature?

Comment: Yes I am. I have disabled it and the menu now works. Thanks very much. Do you know of a solution where I could use view transitions and this menu. Perhaps I could disable view transitions on mobile?

Comment: we have a section in the docs explaining how to update your scripts (https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#script-behavior-during-page-navigation). I'm not 100% sure, but throwing this in an astro:after-swap event may be enough to fix it. if not, I'd read further into how it alters scripts

Answer (score 3):

When using View Transitions, scripts are only loaded once meaning any references to an element will become `null` after they are replaced with a new element from the new page. In order to get around this you can use lifecycle hooks to reinitialize/clean up your scripts

```js
function init() {
  const burger = document.querySelector("#burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector("#nav");

  // Rest of script...

  // Clean up by destroying instances and removing event listeners
  document.addEventListener('astro:before-swap', () => {
    // SomeClass.destroy()
    // document.removeEventListener(...)
  }, { once: true })
}

// Initialize on first load
init()

// Re-initialize after swapping pages
document.addEventListener("astro:after-swap", init)
```

You can also use the [`transition:persist` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#maintaining-state) to prevent an element from being swapped

**View Transition Docs**:

- [Script behavior during page navigation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#script-behavior-during-page-navigation)
- [Lifecycle events](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#lifecycle-events)
- [Maintaining State](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#maintaining-state)

Comment: Nice thank you so much, in my case the transition:persist directive did the work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using astro:after-swap, since when occupying view transition, it conflicts with the execution of events and they are lost.
Now you only send to call your event and it executes it.
(https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#astroafter-swap)

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to solve the problem by installing preact and using a tsx component with useState and useEffect. Since everytime the pages are changed, the content seems to be reloaded but the variables aren`t being kept.

It seems like it might have something to do with Astro`s components life cycles which I haven`t understood well so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).